# ValidationRules in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, dataset

I am populating a DataGrid with a DataSet.
 I have my dataGrid enabled for validationRules by make in each DataGridColumn `ValidatesOnDataError=True` but when I added a `DataGridRow` that has DataErrors then the `DataGridRow` is blocked and I cannot do anything else neither correct the `DataGridRow`

```
     <!--Template for DataGridRow in Error state-->        
                <ControlTemplate x:Key="BasicRowValidationErrorTemplate">
                    <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>

     <!--Style for DataGridCell in static mode-->
            <Style x:Key="textBlockInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                  Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

    <!--Style for DataGridCell in edit mode-->
            <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                  Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

And I have defined my Columns like

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
      <DataErrorValidationRule ValidationStep="ComittedValue"/>
   </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding Nombre, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource textBlockInError}" 
                                        EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"/>    
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Price">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource textBlockInError}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=2},
                                    Path=DataContext.Prices}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayMember" 
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Price}" IsEditable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, AncestorLevel=2},
                                            Path=DataContext.IsComboBoxEditable, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have in my ViewModel

```
DataTable Price;
DataTable Prices;
```

Price has two columns Name and Price
and Prices has two columns DisplayMember and ValueMember

I get the Precios from a file, if the file is not loaded then I do not have precies to show so I made Editable my combobox when i do not have the file. And just set my selected value with the one that user wrote

```
private void ComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox.IsEditable)
    {
        comboBox.SelectedValue = (sender as ComboBox).Text;
    }
}
```

Why is blocked my DataGridRow ?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/187b2b8f-d403-4bf3-97ad-7f93b4385cdf/#fef4d2ca-d6ea-4043-a2ea-3e54fa218068) helps you.

Comment: Unfortunally I already cancel the edition when the cell losed focus but now the problem comes just in one cell I edit my cell and every thing is fine but if I edit my cell with data erros then the template for error is show and when try to edit again the error is raised